# Vector Calculus - Laplacian operator for product of scalar fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given scalar fields $f,g$, I wish to compute the laplacian $\nabla^2(fg)$. I want to do this using index notation. We know that $[\nabla f]_a=D_af$; I suspect we could use the product rule to get $\nabla(fg)=f\nabla g+g\nabla f$, but how do we apply the gradient function $\nabla$ to this sum?

Answer (score 1):

Use the product rule for divergence:

$$\nabla \cdot (f v) = \nabla f \cdot v + f \nabla \cdot v$$
for scalar function $f$ and vector field $v$.